# How do I correctly split up Google App Engine project which uses JPA into a multi-module Maven setup

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, jpa, datanucleus

I have a project for Google App Engine which uses JPA/Datanucleus to access some Entities. That works fine so far.

Now I would like to extract the JPA Entities into a base project in order to re-use the classes in other maven projects to avoid code-duplication.

However when I move the sources into a base project and do the enhancement there with the maven-datanucleus-plugin, running the local app engine server fails with Exceptions like

```
NoPersistenceInformationException: The class "x.y.z" is required to be persistable yet no Meta-Data/Annotations can be found for this class. Please check that the Meta-Data/annotations is defined in a valid file location.
```

I have verified that enhancement seems to be fine, I see

```
DataNucleus Enhancer completed with success for 2 classes
```

however the directory target/generated-sources/annotations is empty, should I be seeing anything in there?

Is it possible to separate the JPA classes into a separate maven project? Or do I need to set up my projects differently?

And how can I verify on the class-files if they are actually enhanced or not?

Comment: How can you verify bytecode enhancement? by using a java decompiler like http://jd.benow.ca/

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I hoped there might be a way using some datanucleus tools or maven plugin.